# AWS Cognito SignOut Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm using the latest version of the AWS SDK's for Android.

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.7.6'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.7.6'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.7.6'
```

My Authentication Handler is taken from their example code for the most part.

```
    // create a handler for the sign-in process
    private AuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler = new AuthenticationHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CognitoUserSession userSession, CognitoDevice newDevice) {
//            String idToken = userSession.getIdToken().getJWTToken();
//            Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<>();
//            logins.put("cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/" + getString(R.string.user_pool_id), idToken);
//            AuthHelper.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider().setLogins(logins);
//
//            new RefreshCognitoCredentials().execute();

            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void getAuthenticationDetails(AuthenticationContinuation authenticationContinuation, String userId) {
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            AuthenticationDetails authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(userId, password, null);
            authenticationContinuation.setAuthenticationDetails(authenticationDetails);
            authenticationContinuation.continueTask();
        }

        @Override
        public void getMFACode(MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation continuation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void authenticationChallenge(ChallengeContinuation continuation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
            String error = AuthHelper.formatException(exception);
            layoutUsername.setErrorEnabled(true);
            layoutUsername.setError(error);
        }
    };
```

Authentication works just fine. And it caches as it should.
In my splashscreen activity I am able to check the CognitoUser.getCurrentUser().getUserId().

And now to logout:

```
CognitoUser.getCurrentUser().signOut()
```

Now, if I close the app and open the app - CognitoUser.getCurrentUser().getUserId() still returns my previously logged in user.

I had done an AWS implementation a few months ago with 2.2.+ as my sdk versions and this example worked as expected.

Note* If I try CognitoUser.getCurrentUser().globalSignout() - it returns a 'user is not authenticated' error.

How can I check on app start-up if I have a valid user/session? I hate how AWS changes things on a daily basis with no documentation or documentation that is impossible to find.

Comment: How do you access to `inputPassword`/android thing there? in the Cognito class!

Answer (score 1):

`signOut` clears the cached tokens from the SharedPreferences. It clears the data stored under access, id and refresh tokens. However the LastAuthUser key contains the user id which is not cleared by signOut.

When you call `cognitoUserPool.getCurrentUser().getUserId()`, it checks for the presence of LastAuthUser key in SharedPreferences, hence it returns the userId. I am looking into the issue. Will update this answer when I can confirm the intended behavior.

Comment: The documentation states that "This has cleared all tokens and this user will have to go through the authentication process to get tokens."

Is there a method I'm not seeing to check to see if the tokens have been cleared? I can replicate the differences between the two versions of the library. signOut cleared the user session and returned null for getUserId(), but now it does not. I'm just trying to figure out what changed and what I need to do.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-android-sdk.html

Comment: I believe I am supposed to be using getSession() instead of checking the userId. It seems to be working as expected.

Comment: Yes, you can definitely call `getSession()` after the user signed out to present SignIn again. However I will get back to you on the reason for the change in behavior on `getUserId()`. Thanks!

Comment: getSession() only works if the user has logged in via Cognito User Pool, not from a federated identity provider? Do I really have to do all the token parsing manually?

Comment: @Karthikeyan here i have one question about getUserId(). when app opens after long interval time getUserId returns null. So here i have to clear all cache and re login again?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this when updating users' emails. In my case, cognito is not updating the value of the last authenticated user when a user switches back to a previously used email.

My solution was to manually update the value in shared preferences where cognito updates the last authenticated user:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("CognitoIdentityProviderCache", 0).edit();
String csiLastUserKey = "CognitoIdentityProvider." + cognitoUserPool.getClientId() + ".LastAuthUser";
editor.putString(csiLastUserKey, newEmail);
editor.commit();
```

This is a hacky workaround since I'm forcing what cognito should do automatically.

Answer (score 0):

### It seems that it is a bug in AWS SDK.

I have almost the same issue. 
My steps:

```
 1. Sign in as user 1
 2. Sing out
 3. Sign in as user 2
 4. Surprise that user 1 is signed in instead of user 2
```

So, decided to upgrade to new SDK

`com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.13.4`

which uses

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.4'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.13.4'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.13.4'
```

But it does not help.

### During the investigation, it was found that

Issue related to file CognitoIdentityProviderCache.xml at /data/data/applicationId/shared_prefs/CognitoIdentityProviderCache.xml

**CognitoIdentityProviderCache.xml file is not cleared after signout.**

File content after signout example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="CognitoIdentityProvider.app_id.LastAuthUser.encrypted">...</string>
    <string name="CognitoIdentityProvider.app_id.LastAuthUser.encrypted.iv">...</string>
    <string name="CognitoIdentityProvider.app_id.LastAuthUser.encrypted.keyvaluestoreversion">1</string>
</map>
```

***Removing this 3 lines from file fixes the issue.***

**The workaround:**

1. Clear file on sign out.

But file name can be changed in the next version.

2. Clear App Internal folder. (applied one)

It is the same as pressing "Clear data" at System Settings -> App -> AwesomeApp

```
 context.cacheDir.parentFile.deleteRecursively()
```

You can follow my bug report for details at their bug tracker

https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/1015